# MYSQL 5.6.12 Lock wait timeout exceeded, yet no transactions\locks currently taking place?

Tags: mysql

On a development database with no other users other than myself, I'm getting the following error `#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` **instantly** when trying to run a simple alter statement.

```
ALTER TABLE proposals ADD STATUS INT( 1 ) NULL AFTER propnum ;
```

if I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I get the following.

```
=====================================
2013-08-17 20:51:54 fa8 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 46 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 935 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 104952 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 105884
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 399
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 408
Mutex spin waits 267, rounds 3238, OS waits 94
RW-shared spins 281, rounds 8430, OS waits 281
RW-excl spins 17, rounds 770, OS waits 23
Spin rounds per wait: 12.13 mutex, 30.00 RW-shared, 45.29 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 29698
Purge done for trx's n:o < 29691 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 1091
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 1278, OS thread handle 0xfa8, query id 9178 localhost ::1 david init
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: wait Windows aio (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: wait Windows aio (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
501 OS file reads, 3733 OS file writes, 1948 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 591553, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 13235364
Log flushed up to   13235364
Pages flushed up to 13235364
Last checkpoint at  13235364
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
1045 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 305856512; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 113054
Buffer pool size   18240
Free buffers       17691
Database pages     547
Old database pages 209
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 450, created 97, written 2355
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 547, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread id 1404, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 298, updated 336, deleted 9, read 136560
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows...

```
2   david   localhost:61155 office  Sleep   2       
335 david   localhost:64481 office  Query   0   init    show full processlist
```

`SHOW OPEN TABLES` does not have any non-zero values

mysql error log has nothing since my last service restart yesterday.

To my limited knowledge, I don't see any pending transactions.  If I stop\restart the MySql service, I can run the statement, but this is the 5th time such an error has occurred and I would like to get to the bottom of it so I can learn what is going wrong, if that's possible.  This is just a simple web application and nothing else is going on with the DB that I know of anyways...